# Is this rocket design from 'The Americans' credit sequence real?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, identify-this-object, soviet-union

In the [opening credit sequence of the TV show 'The Americans'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aI5lCYHqJbo), a schematic of a rocket with 5 strap-on boosters is briefly shown:

[image]

The diagram appears immediately after an elevation view of a Soyuz rocket. The layout is reminiscent of Soyuz, though the details differ. Is it a real rocket design?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The design is fictional.

The boosters appear to be adapted from [this schematic of the Soyuz](https://drawingdatabase.com/soyuz-rocket/), with some roman numeral and Cyrillic letter call-outs pulled from other parts of the drawing, but with the boosters redrawn to have three nozzles each, and a new core stage drawn with 15 nozzles. No Russian engine design that I'm aware of uses a three-chamber design analogous to the 4-chamber engines used on Soyuz, and there are too many similarities between the Soyuz schematic and this design for it to be coincidence.

I went through Asif Siddiqi's ["The Soviet Space Race With Apollo"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0813026288), which describes various Soviet heavy launcher designs both real and notional, and none of them bore any resemblance to this one.

[This interview with an animator](http://creativebabble.com/deciphering-fx-americans-opening-title-sequence-elastic/) who worked on the credits suggests that much of the imagery was adapted and redrawn from real sources, and I believe this rocket design is such a case.